# Associate Azure AppService to a Subnet

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

Ive created an Azure app service in my VPN. My VPN has a few subnets, but I need my AppService to use just a specific subnet. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any way of linking the AppService to a subnet. I need the traffic on that subnet to pass through a special NSG.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The multi-tenant App Service connects to your VNET over Point-to-site VPN, it will use the Point-to-site address space as source IP address. Conversely, App Service **Isolated** (ASE/ASEv2) is deployed in a subnet inside the VNET.

Assuming multi-tenant App Service, this is how traffic flows —
[image: multi-tenant App Service]

There is no way to initiate traffic from the VM through the Point-to-site VPN and reach the Web App over the private channel. Only the other way around works. This limitation does not exist in App Service Isolated.

App Service Isolated —
[image: App Service Isolated]